# Undefined display properties in vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I create my vuetify instance like that:

```
export const vuetify = createVuetify({
  ssr: true,
  locale: {
    adapter: createVueI18nAdapter({
      i18n,
      useI18n,
    }),
  },
  display: {
    mobileBreakpoint: 'sm',
    thresholds: {
      xs: 340,
      sm: 540,
      md: 800,
      lg: 1280,
      xl: 1920,
    },
  },
...
```

and add it in plugins registration:

```
app.use(i18n)
    .use(vuetify)
    .use(router)
    .use(pinia)
    .provide(DefaultApolloClient, ApolloClient);
```

but by vuetify display object properties are undefined.
I import display object like that:

```
import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify';
const display = useDisplay();
```

object is defined but most of properties are undefined and I can see that in all components in devtools.
Have someone any idea that I'm doing wrong? e.g. for theme and internationalization it works properly.

Comment: It works when I try it out. Consider adding a sandbox or similar where the issue can be observed.